# command not found when using nvm in fish shell

Tags: command-line, fish

How can I run and use nvm inside a fish shell? I was previously using bash and switched to fish shell and now I'm unable to use nvm. most of the wrappers are not maintained. what other alternatives exist?

Comment: Are you talking about [_Node Version Manager - Simple **bash script** to manage multiple active node.js versions_](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)?

Comment: yes that's what I'm talking about [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 1):

The [nvm README](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#important-notes) mentions that it does not support fish shell.:

> Note: nvm does not support Fish either (see #303). Alternatives exist, which are neither supported nor developed by us:
>
> - bass allows you to use utilities written for Bash in fish shell
> - fast-nvm-fish only works with version numbers (not aliases) but doesn't significantly slow your shell startup
> - plugin-nvm plugin for Oh My Fish, which makes nvm and its completions available in fish shell
> - fnm - fisherman-based version manager for fish

I'm using [fnm](https://github.com/fisherman/fnm) at the moment and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: please note that before `fnm` (which is called nvm.fish rn) you need to install `fisher` plugin manager.